# Is there a possibility to add form input to a certain line in a CSV file with PHP?

Tags: php, csv

Is there a possibility to add form input to a certain row/column in a CSV file?

For example, if a user gives input to a "Name" section -> Adrian Smith. How do I put that name to a CSV file that has headers starting from row 11 with header "Name" and the names should start from row 12? Also if there's a header "Color" in column B row 11, how do I get data to certain columns?

```
$headers = array("Name", "Website");
$data = array(
    array(
      "name" => "Adrian Smith",
      "website" => "http://example.com"
    ),
    array(
      "name" => "Meredith Cooper",
      "website" => "http://example.com"
    ),
);

$fh = fopen("file.csv", "w");

fputcsv($fh, $headers);

foreach($data as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fh, $fields);
}

fclose($fh);
```

I got this far, but this obviously just adds them to the start. I have no idea how to identify certain rows and columns.

Comment: CSV headers are on first line, why you have it on line 11? Consider CSV as array-of-arrays, if you can add new element certain index, your task will be done

Comment: And if on row 11 - then why on 11? Why not 37? 101? 4? What's the logic?

Comment: Oh right, my client has this CSV file where the data should be put, just a sec.

Comment: So in the file the first rows are for client information and the actual product information that should also be filled in the file are on the lower rows 11+. So, what I need to do is put correct information to correct rows/columns in the csv file. Is that possible?